# apache user can not write to .python-eggs

Tags: python, apache, egg, python-egg-cache

I have read that I need to set the `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` environment variable, or install the python library as an uncompressed .egg

Which do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on if you want to make the egg available as a generally available library or just for a single (or a handful of applications). Are you talking about a Trac installation? If so, there are also a handful of alternatives to make the egg available per instance:

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins