# Django: PYTHON_EGG_CACHE, access denied error

Tags: python, django, python-egg-cache

I am deploying my django application on a server, and on last stages I am getting this error:

```
ExtractionError at /admin/

Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.python-eggs'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://go-ban.org/admin/
Exception Type:     ExtractionError
Exception Value:    

Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.python-eggs'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pkg_resources.py in extraction_error, line 887
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.5.2
Python Path:    ['/home/oleg/sites/goban', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.5-linux-i686.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PyAMF-0.5.1-py2.5-linux-i686.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.5', '/usr/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL', '/var/lib/python-support/python2.5']
Server time:    Sun, 6 Dec 2009 14:05:47 +0200
```

Maybe someone come across similar issue?

The strangest thing here is that I am using another django site on this host with no such error :(

#### Related question

- [apache user can not write to .python-eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268015/apache-user-can-not-write-to-python-eggs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you are using some strange setuptools-enabled library.

But anyway, is there a problem for you to setup PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable to any directory writable for application user?

Comment: +1: Set this env variable AND make that directory owned by the Apache user.